# Keras: How to concatenate over a subset of inputs

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, theano

I am training a neural network using Keras and Theano, in which inputs have a format like:

```
[
   [Situation features],
   [Option 1 features],
   [Option 2 features],
]
```

I want to train a model to predict how often each option will be chosen, by making the model learn how to score each option, and how the situation makes differences in score more or less important.

My model looks like:

```
option_inputs = [Input(shape=(NUM_FEATURES,), name='situation_input'),
                  Input(shape=(NUM_FEATURES,), name='option_input_0'),
                  Input(shape=(NUM_FEATURES,), name='option_input_1')]
situation_input_processing = Dense(5, activation='relu', name='situation_input_processing')
option_input_processing = Dense(20, activation='relu', name='option_input_processing')
diversity_neuron = Dense(1, activation='softplus', name='diversity_neuron')
scoring_neuron = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='scoring_neuron')

diversity_output = diversity_neuron(situation_input_processing(journey_inputs[0]))
scoring_outputs = [scoring_neuron(option_input_processing(option_input)) for option_input in option_inputs[1:2]]

logit_outputs = [Multiply()([diversity_output, scoring_output]) for scoring_output in scoring_outputs]
probability_outputs = Activation('softmax')(keras.layers.concatenate(logit_outputs, axis=-1))

model = Model(inputs=option_inputs, outputs=probability_outputs)
```

When trying to get `probability_outputs`, I get the error:

> ValueError: `Concatenate` layer should be called on a list of inputs

The error seems to be triggered because `logit_outputs` is not built iterating through all 3 input feature collections, only out of 2 of them.

Any idea how to work around this problem?

Once the model is trained, I want to observe the outputs of `diversity_neuron` and `scoring_neuron` to learn how to extrapolate the scoring for arbitrary number of options and understand what drives diversity.

Comment: Try: `logit_outputs = [Multiply([diversity_output, scoring_output]) for scoring_output in scoring_outputs]`

Answer (score 1):

I have made these changes to workaround the problem:

1. I'm including the situation features in the beginning of each option
   feature list
2. I have added a layer that can filter the situation
   features from the option inputs. This is made by manually setting
   weights of a non-trainable layer.
3. I then can iterate through all
   inputs in any path of the network

The final code looks like:

```
option_inputs = [Input(shape=(NUM_FEATURES,), name='option_input_0'),
                  Input(shape=(NUM_FEATURES,), name='option_input_1')]
situation_input_filtering = Dense(NUM_SITUATION_FEATURES, activation='linear', name='situation_input_filtering')
situation_input_filtering.trainable = False
situation_input_processing = Dense(5, activation='relu', name='situation_input_processing')
option_input_processing = Dense(20, activation='relu', name='option_input_processing')
diversity_neuron = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='diversity_neuron')
scoring_neuron = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='scoring_neuron')

diversity_outputs = [diversity_neuron(situation_input_processing(situation_input_filtering(option_input))) for
                     option_input in option_inputs]
scoring_outputs = [scoring_neuron(option_input_processing(option_input)) for option_input in option_inputs]

logit_outputs = [Multiply()([diversity_output, scoring_output]) for diversity_output, scoring_output in
                 zip(diversity_outputs, scoring_outputs)]
combined = keras.layers.concatenate(logit_outputs, axis=-1)
probability_outputs = Activation('softmax')(combined)

model = Model(inputs=option_inputs, outputs=probability_outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

mask_weights = np.zeros([NUM_FEATURES, NUM_SITUATION_FEATURES])
for i in xrange(NUM_situation_FEATURES):
    mask_weights[i, i] = 1.0

for layer in model.layers:
    if layer.name == 'situation_input_filtering':
        layer.set_weights([mask_weights, np.zeros(NUM_SITUATION_FEATURES)])
```